# sitecore comments list to article

Tags: .net, comments, sitecore

I need to add function of comments to my blog.
I have an article. And I need after that article comments section.

Maybe I'm stupid but I don't know how to solve that...

Can you tell me any ideas or send URL for some examples of this?

I use sitecore to build my articles in sections and xslt to build view of this articles.

Sample `xsl:template` to my article:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
  <xsl:variable name = "siteRoot" select="ancestor-or-self::item[sc:IsItemOfType('ArticlePage',.)]"/>
  <div>
    <h2>
      <sc:html select = "$siteRoot" field="Article_Title"/>
    </h2>
    <h6>
      <sc:html select="$siteRoot" field="Article_Date" />
    </h6>
    <sc:html select = "$siteRoot" field="Article_Content" />
    <br />
    <div class="CommentRegion">
      Comments must be here
    </div>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Maybe use some external comments apps like **Disqus** or **Facebook Comments** comments? It's like half an hour integration.

Comment: @MarasMusielak no =) It isn't fine in my case

Comment: You can check how this is solved in Weblog module ( http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx )

Comment: I would also look into storing comments in some other way, especially if you expect a lot of comments. If there are only a few, you could just have them as children. But if there are more than a handful I would think it would get too messy. You could try: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx

Comment: @MarasMusielak thx. I look at it now

Comment: @Holger I do not mind storing comments in other place. thx for url

Comment: What about using a "Bucket"?

Comment: Also consider using a secondary content database (running in "live mode") http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2009/05/working-with-multiple-content-databases.html although I agree with Maras' first comment

Comment: If possible I always opt for a 3rd party comment system like Disqus. But if you are looking for any type of user generated content these days in Sitecore then you should consider a combination of Item Buckets and the Sitecore Item Web API (with a custom publishing action in the web API).